# Data transfer from ADLS Gen 1 of one tenant (Tenant1) to ADLS 2 Gen 2 of second tenant (Tenant 2)

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-data-lake

I have a use-case, where the requirement is to transfer Data from ADLS Gen 1 of one Tenant (Tenant 1) to ADLS 2 Gen 2 of second Tenant (Tenant 2).

A migration of older integrated data into ADLS Gen 2 for centralized cloud platform under a new Tenant.

Please help/suggestion/Guidance.. Really appreciated.

Regards
Prabin

Comment: .Hi, any update? Have you test?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can achieve by azure data factory.

You can use the [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), set the gen1 as the source and gen2 as the sink.